# Buffer priority

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I want to create a buffer based on a field, there are areas that are within 2 distances, for example an area is covered by a distance of 1000 and  a portion of the same area is covered by a distance of 500, so I have overlapping polygons. I just want an output with non overlapping polygons where a priority settled...I mean areas of 250 first, areas of 500 second..and so on[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the 250 values and create the buffer. Select the 500 values and create the buffer.  Erase from 500 buffer the 250 buffer. Select 1000 values, buffer, erase the 500 and 250 from 1000.  Merge all three resulting erases together.

Comment: It seems to work GBG, isn´t there a way to do it direct, in case I had many values.

Comment: How many values do you have?  Cut and paste in Modelbuilder will get you pretty far if you do not have Python skills.

Comment: I have just 4 values, and your method (buffer and erase ) works well.I just wanted to know a way to do it in just one step.